# Hide data points in nvd3.js scatter chart by shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I successfully build a scatter chart with several series in nvd3.js. nvd3.js provides mechanisms to turn on/off series defined by the "key" in my data. Is it possible to do the same by assigned shapes (i.e. cross, circle, etc.)? I'm able to select all data points with a shape in a complicated manner:

```
var series = d3.selectAll('.nv-series')
    .data();
for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    var values = series[i].values;
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
        if (values[j].shape=='circle') {
              // Do something with 

        }
    }
}
```

But now i don't now to toggle those. The property "disabled" only seems to work for series, not for single data points. i would need something similar here, so that the chart gets actualized with correct alignment after hiding the data points. Any help appreciated cause I'm absolutely no javascript expert and couldn't find anything on the net even after long research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it now with a workaround solution (keeping two data structures, allData and filteredData, and filtering a cloned version of allData):

```
//clone data
filteredData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, allData);
for (var i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
    var values = filteredData[i].values;
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
        if (values[j].shape!=shape) {
            filteredData[i].values.splice(j,1);
            j--;

        }
    }
}

d3.select('#test1 svg').datum(filteredData);
chart.update();
```

Doing it this way, the whole graph gets updated. There are some errors thrown on console, but except some small rendering issues, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to downselect to the elements you want (instead of looping), and then use css to hide the shapes you want to hide.

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-point').filter(function(d){ return d.shape === 'circle' })
  .classed('hidden-point', true);
```

In this example, the `hidden-point` class would contain `visibility: none` or some similar style that hides the points with that class. `d3.selectAll('.hidden-point').classed('hidden-point', false)` will show all hidden points.

Comment: Thank you very much, this definitely works for selecting all elements of a shape (CSS should be visibility:hidden, we can even set it with .style() directly). However, there are two problems left: 1) The layout doesn't seem to adapt to the visibility of elements 2) Any tooltips created do still work. I have one other idea to try: filtering out a clone of the data I set in memory and rebuilding the chart with this data.